# Where do I put a rails method/scope that uses params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scope that uses RubyGeocoder method, `near`, to filter events by location using `param[:searchCity]`. The param gets the user's geolocation so it shows events only near them. I currently have it working in my `events_controller` index action, but I also need to call it on my home page.

Considering it's a filter that gets data from the database, I thought it would be best to go in the model, but I'm finding conflicting information on whether having a param in the model is ok or bad practice. Also, I can't get it to work in the model with the param present.

What's the best practice for something like this? Where should I place the scope, the model, controller, helper, or somewhere else?

Here's my code:

```
Model:
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr, validates, belongs_to etc here.
  scope :is_near, self.near(params[:searchCity], 20, :units => :km, :order => :distance) #doesn't work with the param, works with a "string"
end

Controller:
def index
  unless params[:searchCity].present?
    params[:searchCity] = request.location.city
  end

  @events = Event.is_near

  # below works in the controller, but I don't know how to call it on the home page
  # @events = Event.near(params[:searchCity], 20, :units => :km, :order => :distance)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @events }
  end
end

The line I'm calling in my home page that gets how many events are in the area
<%= events.is_near.size %>
```

**Edit: Using a lambda seems to be working. Is there any reason I shouldn't do it this way?**

```
Model:
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :is_near, lambda {|city| self.near(city, 20, :units => :km, :order => :distance)}
end

Controller:
def index
  @events = Event.is_near(params[:searchCity])
...

home.html.erb
<%= events.is_near(params[:searchCity]).size %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the params in model is not possible. Params is something which is made to exist only at controller and view level.

So best way is to write some helper method in controller to perform this.

```
 Class Mycontroller < ApplicationController
   before_action fetch_data, :only => [:index]

   def fetch_data
     @data = Model.find(params[:id])#use params to use fetch data from db 
   end

   def index

   end
```

Comment: Am I able to use `fetch_data` as a chain method on my home page using this? ex. `<%= events.fetch_data.size %>`?

Comment: not really that way, but you can initialize and then use that initialized veritable with

Comment: Hmm. I had initialization working before but I wasn't able to get an accurate `.size` on the home page. I'll try using with. Is there a reason why it's better split the fetch_data into two actions rather than keep it in the index since I'm only using it there?

Comment: That's perfectly alright to put those processing in action itself. We use `before_action`(in rails3 before_filter) to share the processing with different actions like to load some default data needed in more that one action.

Comment: This isn't fully true. You can pass values from `params` in the controller into the model. You can either pass the value(s) as arguments in custom model methods or as arguments in scopes (as demonstrated in the update to the question). That said, creating a before filter is not the cleanest way to handle this. That makes for a fat controller. Not good.

Comment: @ChrisPeters so is using a lambda the right way to do this according to Rails best practices?

Comment: @ChrisPeters,what do you think is the best way to handle this?

Comment: BHOLT, of course you can write lambda scope in filter instead of just finders, like @events = Event.is_near(params[:searchCity])